# Why form is not auto-sized for current resolution?

Tags: ios, delphi, retina-display, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have an Firemonkey HD application and deploy it on iPad 2.
Works fine.

When I deploy the same app on iPad 4 with Retina display I get problems.

The point is I have some drawing operations on a form and need exact form width and height.

```
ShowMessage('form wh = ' + FloatToStr(TForm(FImage.Parent.Parent). Width) + ':' + FloatToStr(TForm(FImage.Parent.Parent).Height));
```

on both devices I get a message:

```
form wh = 1024:748
```

What I need is automatic form size change.

What should I do to get it?

**UPDATE:** I try to use Screen.Size.Width but have Screen.Size.Width=1024 on Retina display. What do I do wrong?

Comment: The form should be full screen (auto-sizes to match screen). Between retina and non-retina screen, the size will be the same, it's the scale that changes. Can you describe the issue in more detail or include an image of the issue?

Comment: Yes, sure. The form is full screen. The strange point for me is I have Screen.Size.Width=1024 and Screen.Size.Height=768. What details do you want to get. I will provide them with pleasure.

Comment: Since the form is full screen, it's obviously auto-sizing. What's the actual issue? This? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_Layout_to_Adjust_Different_Form_Sizes_or_Orientations_%28iOS_and_Android%29

Comment: Closest solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124191/how-to-find-resolution-under-delphi-xe5. But when I try to get screen structure I get an access violation (0x000000) exception...

Comment: Wait, you mean that `SupportsPlatformService` call returned you True in that code and if you then tried to access `ScreenSvc` interface, it failed with an access violation ? That would be a critical bug, since the way provided in that code is a proper way...

Comment: See [Using Multi-resolution bitmaps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Using_Multi-Resolution_Bitmaps) for a discussion of screen resolution (size, as in width and height), screen density (pixels per inch), and screen scale (logical vs physical coordinates and sizes).

Comment: Also see [Working with Native and Custom FireMonkey Styles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Working_with_Native_and_Custom_FireMonkey_Styles), which discusses Retina displays and resolution (1x vs 2x).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to your 'update', you need to consider the difference between the number of 'device' pixels vs. the number of 'logical' pixels. Typically, a 'retina' display isn't physically larger than a non-'retina' one (or if it is, that's nothing to do with being 'retina' as such) - instead, it has a much higher resolution. Further, the point of this higher resolution isn't to cram more controls (views) into the same physical screen size - it's to make the display clearer, less 'blocky' up close.

As such, the number of logical pixels - the units used to size controls - does not go up just because of a 'retina' display. This is why `IFMXScreenService.GetScreenSize` is returning the same result with 'retina' and non-'retina' displays. However, `IFMXScreenService` has another method, `GetScreenScale`, that you can use to derive the screen size in 'device' pixels:

```
uses FMX.Platform;

function GetScreenSizeInDevicePixels: TPointF;
var
  Service: IFMXScreenService;
begin
  Service := IFMXScreenService(
    TPlatformServices.Current.GetPlatformService(IFMXScreenService));
  Result := Service.GetScreenSize * Service.GetScreenScale;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, your way with GetScreenScale() is ok for me. Thanks a lot.